# Call an Activity that is not a fragment activity on Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new in Android Studio. I have a Navigation Drawer and I am trying to call an activity which is not a fragment activity and I am confused about it. I want to call the RecipeActivity to add in the Navigation Drawer but that activity extends AppCompatActivity and not a Fragment. How can I fix this?

RecipeActivity.java

```
public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Recipe> listRecipe;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_recipe);

        

        RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, listRecipe);
        myRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        myRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

}
```

The HomePage.java contains the navigation drawer code

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_draw_open, R.string.navigation_draw_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null){

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();

        navigationView.setCheckedItem((R.id.nav_home));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_recipe:
                //startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RecipeActivity.class));


                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeActivity.class));
               //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                     //  new RecipeActivity()).commit();

               // Intent newIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, RecipeActivity.class);
               // startActivity(newIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your
`startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeActivity.class));`
to `startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RecipeActivity.class));`

And make sure that all the Activities are added in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I forgot it, that fixed my problem. Thank you!